# How to resolve a java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 why?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Don't understand why the error shows

> java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

My code is

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<% 
String ime = request.getParameter ("ime");   
String priimek = request.getParameter ("priimek");      
String spol = request.getParameter ("spol");   
String email= request.getParameter ("email");      
String gsm = request.getParameter ("gsm");       
String datumr = request.getParameter ("datumr");  
String subject = request.getParameter ("subject");   
String q1 = request.getParameter ("q1");    
String q2 = request.getParameter ("q2");   
String q3 = request.getParameter ("q3");      
String q4 = request.getParameter ("q4");       
String q5 = request.getParameter ("q5");  
String q6 = request.getParameter ("q6");   
String q7 = request.getParameter ("q7");    
String q8 = request.getParameter ("q8");   
String q9 = request.getParameter ("q9");      
String q10 = request.getParameter ("q10");       

Connection con = null; 
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try { 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/zora", "zora", 
"zora0101"); 
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate ("INSERT INTO stranki (ime, priimek, spol, email, gsm, 
datumr, subject, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10) VALUES 
('"+ime+"', '"+priimek+"', '"+spol+"', '"+email+"','"+gsm+"', 
'"+datumr+"', '"+subject+"', '"+q1+"', '"+q2+"', '"+q3+"', '"+q4+"', 
'"+q5+"', '"+q6+"' '"+q7+"', '"+q8+"', '"+q9+"', '"+q10+"')"); 
} catch(Exception e) %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please learn how to use prepared statements with parameters. Your current code is unsafe as it is vulnerable to SQL injection. In addition, it is very hard to read (which makes it easy to miss errors like yours). You're missing a comma between `'"+q6+"'` and `'"+q7+'"`.

Answer (score -1):

It happen sometimes don't worry. your are missing comma in your code :

```
VALUES 

    ('"+ime+"', '"+priimek+"', '"+spol+"', '"+email+"','"+gsm+"', 
    '"+datumr+"', '"+subject+"', '"+q1+"', '"+q2+"', '"+q3+"', '"+q4+"', 
    '"+q5+"', '"+q6+"'**comma missing here** '"+q7+"', '"+q8+"', '"+q9+"', '"+q10+"')"); 
    }
```

corrected code:

```
VALUES 
('"+ime+"', '"+priimek+"', '"+spol+"', '"+email+"','"+gsm+"', 
'"+datumr+"', '"+subject+"', '"+q1+"', '"+q2+"', '"+q3+"', '"+q4+"', 
'"+q5+"', '"+q6+"', '"+q7+"', '"+q8+"', '"+q9+"', '"+q10+"')"); 
}
```

Hope it solve your problem.